# How to Get Data From Model in Function With Laravel

Tags: laravel, function, laravel-5, model, mutators

Is it possible to get data from the model in a function? I want to get the SupplierID data from the Product model.

```
public function productAjax($id)
{
    $product = new Producttext();
    $products = $product->productexts($id);
    $hitung_products = $products->count();

    $suplierproduct = Company::select('id', 'CompanyName')
        ->where(['id' => $products->SupplierID])
        ->first();
}
```

However, on execution, I get the following error.

> Property [SupplierID] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Do you have `SupplierID` in your `Producttext` model?

Comment: yup, i have it...

Comment: @Jazuly `$products` is currently a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) of product objects or array of products if you wish. Given that you wish to query a single product, make sure to retrieve the correct one.

Comment: First get the Proper product text and then compare or find the Company with SupplierID

Comment: @DsRaj how i can do it, im still learning about laravel, can u please some code, so i can learn from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have producttext `ID` then

```
$product = Producttext::find($id)
```

OR

```
$product = Producttext::where('id',$id)->first();


//test and check that you have it $product->SupplierID

$suplierproduct = Company::select('id', 'CompanyName')->where('id',$product->SupplierID)
->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function productajax($id)
{
    $products = Producttext::where('id',$id)->first();

    $suplierproduct = Company::select('id', 'CompanyName')
    ->where(['id' => $products->SupplierID])
    ->first();
}
```